# Django form validation when editing existing Model with a FileField

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I have an issue with form validation when editing a Model that has a `FileField`.

My model has two `FileField`, one that is mandatory, one that is not:

**models.py**

```
class Entrega(models.Model):
    """ People's submissions """

    tid = models.AutoField(_('Código de entrega'), primary_key=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    memoria = models.FileField(upload_to=user_upload_memoria_directory_path)
    anexos = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=user_upload_anexos_directory_path)
```

The same view should be able to create new `Entrega` or edit existing one.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('entregas/<int:pk>/edit/', views.edit_or_create_Entrega, name='edit_create_entrega'),
    path('entregas/new/', views.edit_or_create_Entrega, name='edit_create_entrega'),
    ...
]
```

**views.py (not working, see below)**

```
@login_required
def edit_or_create_Entrega(request, pk=None):
    """ Shows the form to create/edit Entrega's """
    if request.method == "POST":
        # create form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = EntregaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            nueva_entrega = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list_all_entregas'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'envio/base.html', {'avisos': _("Errors were found...")})
    else:
        if not pk:
            # if a GET (or any other method) and no pk is provided, create a blank form
            form = EntregaForm()
        else:
            # if GET (or any other method) and pk is provided, we'll fill the form with
            # entrega, if it exists and it belongs to the user
            e = get_object_or_404(Entrega,pk=pk)
            if not e.matricula.persona.user==request.user:
                return render(request, 'envio/base.html', {'avisos': _("You cannot edit other users submissions")})
            else:
                form = EntregaForm(instance=e)

    return render(request, 'envio/entrega_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**views.py (new version, it works, see below)**

```
@login_required
def edit_or_create_Entrega(request, pk=None):
    """ Shows the form to create/edit Entrega's """
    if request.method == "POST" and not pk:
        # create form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = EntregaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            nueva_entrega = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list_all_entregas'))
    elif request.method == "POST" and pk:
        e = get_object_or_404(Entrega,pk=pk)
        if not e.matricula.persona.user==request.user:
            return render(request, 'envio/base.html', {'avisos': _("Solo puedes editar tus propias Entregas")})
        else:
            form = EntregaForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=e)
            if form.is_valid():
                edit_entrega = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list_all_entregas'))
    else:
        if not pk:
            # if a GET (or any other method) and no pk is provided, we'll create a blank form
            form = EntregaForm()
            matriculas = Matricula.objects.filter(persona__user=request.user)
            if not matriculas:
                return render(request,'envio/base.html', {'avisos': _("No hay matriculas disponibles")})
        else:
            # if GET (or any other method) and pk is provided, we'll fill the form with
            # entrega, if it exists and it belongs to the user
            e = get_object_or_404(Entrega,pk=pk)
            if not e.matricula.persona.user==request.user:
                return render(request, 'envio/base.html', {'avisos': _("Solo puedes editar tus propias Entregas")})
            else:
                form = EntregaForm(instance=e)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EntregaForm(ModelForm):
    """ Modela un formulario para realizar Entregas """

    class Meta:
        model = Entrega
        fields = ['titulo', ... , 'memoria', 'anexos']
```

With the *not working, see below*, this is what happened:

- First time I go to `entregas/6/edit` the form is correctly pre-filled with the values stored in the database. It even shows the "current" `memoria` value (and gives the option to upload a new file)
- If I make changes in some field, for instance, `titulo` and Submit the form without uploading a new `memoria`file, the `form.is_valid()`returns `false` (and the instance is not updated).
- If I make changes in the `memoria`and `title`field, a NEW `Entrega`is saved (does not update the existing one).

Now with the *new version, it works* it does update the existing Entrega.

For the sake of completeness, I will complete my code with the two functions that deal with files that are not being used in `models.py`:

**models.py**

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Entrega)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes file from filesystem
    when corresponding 'Entrega' object is deleted.
    Refactor? Perhaps it would be better to use django-cleanup https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup
    """
    if instance.memoria:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.memoria.path):
            os.remove(instance.memoria.path)
    if instance.anexos:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.anexos.path):
            os.remove(instance.anexos.path)

@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=Entrega)
def auto_delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes old file from filesystem when corresponding 'Entrega' object is updated with new file.
    This function assumes that EVERY entrega has a mandatory 'memoria' field!!
    Refactor? Perhaps it would be better to use django-cleanup https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    try:
        old_memoria = Entrega.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).memoria
    except Entrega.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    new_memoria = instance.memoria
    if new_memoria and not old_memoria == new_memoria:
        if os.path.isfile(old_memoria.path):
            os.remove(old_memoria.path)

    old_anexos = None
    try:
        old_anexos = Entrega.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).anexos
    except Entrega.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    # if there were NO old_anexos, no need to do nothing...
    if not old_anexos:
        return True
    # if there were old_anexos, remove them... 
    new_anexos = instance.anexos
    if new_anexos and not old_anexos == new_anexos:
        if os.path.isfile(old_anexos.path):
            os.remove(old_anexos.path)
```

Comment: I was missing to pass the instance in POST. Editing my original post.

Comment: is the last issue (new Entraga saved) happening after your change? You should just delete the 'not working' version from your post, it's not clear now what isn't working.

Comment: Updated the original question with the `views.py` that works.

Comment: so you should mark the answer below as correct, since that helped you answer the question.

Comment: @dirkgroten done, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistake in your code. When you make a POST request, then you have to check the `pk` value. If pk is there then you should update the Model otherwise save new instance.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if pk and form.is_valid():
        // here update the model
```